# Django messages repeating itself instead of updating

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
classinfo = EventType.objects.all()
length = EventType.objects.all().count()
for i in range(length):
    messages.success(request, classinfo[i])
```

So I'm using this to print out a list of all events that are located in EventType.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoqRz.png)

This is what it looks like. However, when I add another item to the list using the Class Add feature, it repeats the original list again and then adds the additional event. But if I add an additional another event after this it will add it to the list properly. How can I go about fixing this so it doesn't repeat the initial list when I add an event?

[How it looks right now when I add an event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pJIK.png)

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<li>
{{ message }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Django uses the FallbackStorage class, which means that it will first use CookieStorage to store your messages. As long as your cookie does not exceed 2KB, then it will store all your messages in a cookie. What you are doing is creating messages when you run your request, all these messages are stored in a cookie. You then add an event and make another request. The view will then loop through all your EventType's again and add it to the cookie, along with the original content of the cookie from the first request. I don't know why when you add an EventType a third time it shows the list properly, perhaps you are at the size limit of the cookie and it drops its existing contents.

Do you really need to store messages? Messages are used as a logging mechanism. You are using messages to iterate over a model, which is unnecessary. Simply pass classinfo into your context dictionary and iterate over it instead of messages:

view.py:

```
classinfo = EventType.objects.all()
```

template.html:

```
{% for event in classinfo %}
<li>{{ event }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Better yet, simply use Django's ListView, this is exactly what it is for:

```
class EventListView(ListView):
    model = EventType
```